# Faulting system dll then service crashes

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, runtime-error, unhandled-exception

We've got a weird pattern of failure in one of our written services.  We'll get a fault out of a system dll then a minute or so later our service will crash with or without a unhandled exception.

We'll get one of the following faulted module messages from .Net runtime error reporting:

```
faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781
faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.5755
faulting module clbcatq.dll, version 2001.12.4414.700
```

More than 30 seconds (but less than a minute) later we **may or may not** get an exception like:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
System.AccessViolationException
exception in a MSDTC related component
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
```

Has anyone seen this delayed/paired behavior?  Both errors are reported to the event viewer.  This only occurs on some physically-older XP production systems, never in dev.

Comment: You might want to make sure that any rogue threads are not bringing down the service with an unhandled exception.  Is this a multithreaded application?  You might also want to consider an UnhandledException handler to your service to try and see if that catches anything (although there are a few scenarios in which this handler may not catch it).

Comment: Based on the CultureNotFoundException I would assume your physically-older XP production systems need to have Windows XP reinstalled and updated of course.